# useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd when called from script

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu-12.04

I try to add user account but it give me useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later
what should I do I wrote this code

```
echo -n "Enter a number of user account  "
read n

for((i=1;i<n;i++));
    useradd CPE_User$i
done
```

Comment: Might be worth removing the Powershell tag from this question as I can't see any Powershell relation :-)

Comment: That's a problem with `useradd`, not with anything in the shell script itself.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing about that script is wrong, except that it calls `useradd` many times quickly -- if anything started by a previous `useradd` instance (while it held a lock on `/etc/passwd`) is still running, a new instance will fail.

See if that error has a distinct exit status. If it does, you can detect it and try again.

For instance, if that exit status is `5`:

```
useradd "CPE_User$i"; status=$?
case $status in
  0) break ;;
  5) echo "waiting to retry after exit status $status..." >&2
     sleep 1
     continue
     ;;
  *) echo "unexpected exit status $status" >&2
     exit ;;
esac
```

`useradd` is provided by your OS, and is not a standardized tool, so its usage and exit status behavior will vary by platform. You can determine the exit status by checking `$?`.

Another approach you can try (if the problem happens every time around the loop) is to do your own locking:

```
for ((i=1; i<n; i++)); do
  {
    flock -x 200
    useradd CPU_User"$i"
  } 200>/tmp/passwd.lock
done
```

This won't help if something *else* is separately locking `/etc/passwd`, but may solve the problem if something is inheriting `useradd`'s lock (as it will now inherit your lock as well).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i tried doing below operation but no luck

```
rm -rf /etc/*.lock
```

Later, I found the below command which will list hidden lock files as well.

```
find /etc | grep -iE '.lo?ck$'

/etc/selinux/targeted/semanage.read.LOCK
/etc/selinux/targeted/semanage.trans.LOCK
/etc/selinux/targeted/active/modules/100/clock
/etc/selinux/targeted/active/modules/100/sanlock
/etc/selinux/targeted/active/modules/100/vlock
/etc/pam.d/vlock
/etc/.pwd.lock
```

in output, I got the culprit file and after removing this issue got resolved

```
rm -rvf /etc/.pwd.lock
```